# Computer Freeze after latest update

Tags: 20.04

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu.
Yesterday there was a NVIDIA update and an AMD processor update. Now after a few minutes the sound starts repeating and the entire computer freezes forcing me to do a hard shutdown.